# How can i push an object to promises in vueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuex

I have the following function to load categories in vue JS

```
const self = this as any;
self.fetchFeaturedCategories();
```

if i console log self.fetchFeaturedCategories(), it will return promises.
[image]

I would like to achieve something like this (This is in angular):

```
this.categories = categories.map(category => {
const parentCategory = {
  gender: category.gender,
  id: category.id,
  imageUrl: category.imageUrl,
  isFeatured: category.isFeatured,
  name: 'All ' + category.name,
  parent: category.parent,
  parentId: category.parentId,
  slug: category.slug,
  type: category.type,
};
  category.children = [parentCategory, ...category.children];
  return category;
});
```

However, i would like to insert an object to each of the children's array. How can i achieve this? 
Thanks!

Comment: assuming function fetch... returns an array of Promises, `self.fetchFeaturedCategories().map(p=>p.then(x=>x.children['somekey']='somevalue')))`

Comment: is this possible if i'm trying to push an array into the promises? i just edited my question, and i would like to achieve something like that

Comment: hi, insert what to what from where to where?  you mention promise, so if you want to manipulate the Promise's output you would do it in .then or await it and then manipulate.  if you want to manipulate input that generates the Promise, that would depend on the api you are using, and generally should not possible because whatever function you are calling should already have run and is just waiting on I/O (the Promise represents this) by the time you try to change its input.

Comment: i would like to insert parent category (as mentioned above) into the promises in the image.

Comment: does self.fetchFeaturedCategories() return that array or Promises?

Comment: self.fetchFeaturedCategories() returns Promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate Promise resolved values, you have to use .then, or await, to wait for the Promise to resolve and then act on the resolved value and return your new resolved value.

```
  self.fetchFeaturedCategories() // assuming this is an array of Promises
   .then(categories => categories.map(category => {
      const parentCategory = {
        gender: category.gender,
        id: category.id,
        imageUrl: category.imageUrl,
        isFeatured: category.isFeatured,
        name: 'All ' + category.name,
        parent: category.parent,
        parentId: category.parentId,
        slug: category.slug,
        type: category.type,
      };
      const categoryMerged = {
         ...category, children: [parentCategory, ...category.children||[]]
      };
      return categoryMerged;
   }));
```

Comment: i found this error self.fetchFeaturedCategories(...).map is not a function, any ideas why

Comment: `fetchFeaturedCategories`'s return is probably not an array of Promises.  Find where you are running console.log for that Promise array, and insert this operation there, replacing self.fetchFeaturedCategories with what you are console.log ing

Comment: actually I think I misread it. Is it returning a single Promise? this is what you need then

Comment: when i do console.log, it returns the picture i just updated. i tried your solution above but it returns "nonIterableSpread.js?3427:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"

Comment: possibly children is not always defined?  I've added a simple check up there.  this assumes childlren is always an array

Comment: i found a new error now, it returns "[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers." what does this mean?

Comment: vuex is protecting you from mutating store objects directly (you should only ever update store state with mutation handlers).  instead of setting children, use a spread operator or Object.assign to generate a new object with children merged.  Depending on what you are doing, though, this may not be sufficient and you may need to deal with this some where else.  I can't see that part so I can't help with that.  If you are just transforming data as a one-time pass for functions that need that format, you are fine.  If you are storing state data, you need to use a mutation handler

Comment: the ellipses `...` is a spread operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax it is a convenience syntax sugar for iterating over objects or arrays and expanding their values as multiple parameters.  the TypeError is because you cannot iterate undefined (`...undefined` is invalid because you can't iterate undefined)

Comment: ahh i see, now it returns no error, however it doesn't push the object into the promises.

Comment: if you are trying to change the state used by your vue components, this will not work because you have to modify the state through the mutation handlers or change fetch data before your mutation handler receives the data.  This will only change the shape of your data for the current list of fetches you have done.  It will be difficult to help with that without seeing what you are trying to do.

Comment: i tried console.log (categorymerged) and it is the promises that i want. however i would like to display that into my front end. as i was hoping to make a category menu with sub categories. the children being the sub categories. however on the first array, i would like to add "All [Category]" followed by the rest of the children

Comment: so whatever function you have in your vuex store that receives `fetchFeaturedCategories`'s data and updates the store, you will have to call it with your new data.  or change the code that updates the store and have it transform the data as you wanted it here.

Comment: so you can accept the answer as solution that helped you to finalize this question, and upvote the comment that helped you (the last one about the vuex store) so it gets pushed up in the displayed comments.  this will help make this question more useful for future visitors